# Can't convert object of type String to Custom model error in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat feature into my app and I am getting error while reading the value from firebase realtime database. And error is shown in image.

Here is my addValueEventListener method for getting the chats from database.[image]

```
 mMessageDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               // Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue(TeamMessage.class);
                TeamMessage teamMessage = snapshot.getValue(TeamMessage.class);
                Log.d("FirebaseMessage", "Message is: " + teamMessage.getText());
                teamMessages.add(teamMessage);
              //  Log.d("TeamMessage", teamMessage.getText().toString());
            }
```

And here is I am getting reference and setting the value to the database.

```
  mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); // newly added
        mMessageDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("messages"); // newly added
        binding.iconSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // newly added
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = binding.messageEditText.getText().toString();
                TeamMessage teamMessage = new TeamMessage();
                teamMessage.setName(mUsername);
                teamMessage.setText(text);

               mMessageDatabaseReference.push().setValue(teamMessage);
              // Log.d("Message","Message is: "+ mMessageDatabaseReference.get());
                // Clears input box
               binding.messageEditText.setText("");
               hideKeyboard();
            }
        });
```

Here is my TeamMessage model class.

```
public class TeamMessage {
    private String text;
    private String name;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now issue is whenever I am trying to read value from addEventListener method I am not getting and unable to display the chats but I can see message is stored in database.

Here is the database structure in json format.

```
{
  "messages": {
    "-N6wkBpYaBQkdKw-SXee": "",
    "-N6wl4Xy-vNkbSYnBAmp": "hgdg",
    "-N6wl62WLQb15j_fMbSo": "hgdg",
    "-N7-nkD74qMHbJvUUvgP": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-nmbGlbGPVMlKafwr": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-nmmi-R7F6xEceHN9": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-nmrPI1skXb-ywOIg": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-oiEEXcbPvxgZXu1D": "hi everybody",
    "-N7FAvDvOyjUqtvsRJh9": "Hi",
    "-N7FAvE3K-D_RwNHBAQN": "Hi",
    "-N7FC1Em5-njw3KLit8k": "hi",
    "-N7FDE4FH9gYY8ox683S": "hi",
    "-N7FHpph7nlAQALmcbGB": "hi",
    "-N7FsDWxnUhL1DL5HeF6": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "hi"
    },
    "-N7FsQSRXl9RRQ6O09gj": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Hi"
    },
    "-N7Fvd16MOYeFaCMfErB": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "hi"
    },
    "-N7Fw6YVjL7TRT3cvk8r": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "hi"
    },
    "-N7G1o9aYbIdTPGhyugC": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Hey"
    },
    "-N7G5YnGf34Qe0TbbIKD": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Hi"
    },
    "-N7G5sHUkEE4pt8nB3J0": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Saara"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo did that.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: Adding addValueEventListener to databasereference. Snapshot is unable to get value.

Comment: Does Adnan Bashir's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

after checking your msgs JSON file i found the problem ,
acctualy your model is not same type of json .
this json is valid syntext but not valid for your code , you need to delete

```
 "-N6wkBpYaBQkdKw-SXee": "",
    "-N6wl4Xy-vNkbSYnBAmp": "hgdg",
    "-N6wl62WLQb15j_fMbSo": "hgdg",
    "-N7-nkD74qMHbJvUUvgP": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-nmbGlbGPVMlKafwr": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-nmmi-R7F6xEceHN9": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-nmrPI1skXb-ywOIg": "Hi abhas",
    "-N7-oiEEXcbPvxgZXu1D": "hi everybody",
    "-N7FAvDvOyjUqtvsRJh9": "Hi",
    "-N7FAvE3K-D_RwNHBAQN": "Hi",
    "-N7FC1Em5-njw3KLit8k": "hi",
    "-N7FDE4FH9gYY8ox683S": "hi",
    "-N7FHpph7nlAQALmcbGB": "hi",
```

these entries , which is not valid for your mode.

your model except

```
"-N7FsDWxnUhL1DL5HeF6": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "hi"
    },
    "-N7FsQSRXl9RRQ6O09gj": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Hi"
    },
    "-N7Fvd16MOYeFaCMfErB": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "hi"
    },
    "-N7Fw6YVjL7TRT3cvk8r": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "hi"
    },
    "-N7G1o9aYbIdTPGhyugC": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Hey"
    },
    "-N7G5YnGf34Qe0TbbIKD": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Hi"
    },
    "-N7G5sHUkEE4pt8nB3J0": {
      "name": "anonymous",
      "text": "Saara"
    }
```

this type of data ,

Comment: I have deleted the data from database which wasn't matching the defined model. Error remains the same. This time I have also applied loop over snapshot.getChildren() but message null is receiving in Logcat.

Comment: This really should solve the error you get though. If you still have an error after changing the code and data as Adnan described, I recommend opening a new question for  remaining problem, with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the JSON of the updates database, the updated code, and the error message you now get (also as text please, no screenshots are needed for textual content).